# How do I add from one column only when string matches in another?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

trying to add up numbers from one column only when it matches the string in another
for instance, add ints in col2 when col1 is A.

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'col1': ['A', 'B', 'A', 'B'], 'col2': [1, 2, 1, 2]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`DataFrame.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) + [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html)

```
df.loc[df.col1.eq('A'), 'col2'] = df.groupby('col1')['col2'].transform('sum')
print(df)
```

Or

```
new_df = df.assign(col2=df.groupby('col1')['col2'].transform('sum').where(df.col1.ne('A'),
                                                                          df.col1))
```

**Output**

```
  col1  col2
0    A     2
1    B     2
2    A     2
3    B     2
```